# What are the WordPress analogs\clones that would run under Google App Engine?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, wordpress, blogs

So I want it to run on free google app engine version, I want it to be more or less structured like WP (meaning end user experience). I need clean readable source so I could change it as I wish.

If there are no such alike WP ones than some other Blog Engine would work for me.

What are the WordPress analogs\clones that would run under Google App Engine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blog engine for Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086465/blog-engine-for-google-app-engine)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804368/blogging-system-which-runs-on-the-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Roller](http://roller.apache.org/) is a good Java-based blog engine. I'm not sure if it works with GAE but I can't see why it wouldn't.